# Handling EPR spin-probes, specifically how to dissolve 5-DSA?

Tags: epr-spectroscopy

I want to do some EPR tests with 5-DSA (or related spin probe) dissolved into different crude oils.

It had not sunk into me that $100 of 5-DSA was a tiny amount of a very sticky solid. It's proving hard to deploy in each test. Better would be if I could dissolve my 5-DSA into, say, known volume of toluene and then pipette a few mL of that toluene mixture into the oil sample.

But is toluene the right answer? I don't want to destroy the free radical. How do other researchers handle their spin-probes?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you should make some solution of 5-doxylstearic acid , but toluene is somewhat prone to make benzyl radicals...

Comment: For the -DSA and -DSE spin-radicals, what worked really well was to dissolve in a bit of toluene and leave overnight. The left a very thin layer of the spin-probe in the test tube. I could then add water or whatever and the radicals would spin around desperately searching for something to latch onto and then I could do experiments (eg micelles in water). Putting them in toluene and adding the toluene mix was less interesting because they stayed in the toluene and didnt go away and latch onto anything else....